# Loop until grep does not find the text in a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, grep

I have a file named `file.txt`. The content of the file is as follows

```
sunday
monday
tuesday
```

I wrote the below script and it loops just fine if the `grep` cannot find the pattern that was mentioned

```
until cat file.txt | grep -E "fdgfg" -C 9999; do sleep 1 | echo "working..."; done
```

But my requirement is that the above script should loop until the text mentioned in the `grep` pattern disappears in the  `file.txt`

I tried to use the `L` flag with grep. But it didn't work.

```
until cat file.txt | grep -EL "sunday" -C 9999; do sleep 1 | echo "working..."; done
```

Comment: So essentially , you want to print everything until the line that has "sunday" in it , correct ?

Comment: @Serg: No. I want to execute the `do` part until the `grep` part does not find  `sunday` in the `file.txt`. Assume that some process modifies the `file.txt` and removed `sunday` from the file while the `until.....` statement is running

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From `grep` man page:

```
EXIT STATUS
   Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were
   selected, and 2 if an error occurred.  However, if the -q or --quiet or
   --silent is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0  even  if
   an error occurred.
```

So if a line is present, the exit status is 0. Since on bash 0 is true (because the standard "successful" exit status of programs is 0) you should actually have something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while grep "sunday" file.txt > /dev/null;
do
    sleep 1
    echo "working..."
done
```

Why exactly are you piping `sleep 1` to `echo`? Though it works, it doesn't make much sense. If you wanted them inline you could just write `sleep 1; echo "working..."` and if you wanted the `echo` to run before the delay, you could have it before the `sleep` call like `echo "working..."; sleep 1`.

Comment: Just use `grep "sunday" file.txt` ,avoid  useless use of cat

Comment: Also, `grep` can be redirected to `/dev/null` or use `--quiet` option

Comment: Another cat saved from cat abuse! Thanks @Serg. I corrected the code, just a note: `--quiet` option would actually break the code here, because then the exit status would always be 0. Redirecting the output to `/dev/null` should do it though!

Comment: @Serg I think in that case the loop wouldn't even start, because even when a match is found the exit status will be 0 and then reversed to 1 breaking out of the loop.

Comment: @IanC actually, it works perfectly fine. I just tested this : http://paste.ubuntu.com/23483503/

Comment: @Serg You're right! It does work with `--quiet` too. I misinterpreted the `grep` manual. It says with `--quiet` the output will also be 0 when an error occurs, but the output is still 1 if a match is not found!

Comment: If you wanna have the reverse functionality (loping while it's NOT there) just replace while with until keyword.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true ; do 
  echo "Working..."
  result=$(grep -nE 'sunday' file.txt) # -n shows line number
  echo "DEBUG: Result found is $result"
  if [ -z "$result" ] ; then
    echo "COMPLETE!"
    break
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Followings works for me, I dont know why while loop didnt work

```
until echo "$(kubectl -n production get pods -l=app='activemq' -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[0].ready}')" | grep -q "true"; do
   sleep 10
   echo "Waiting for Broker to be ready......................."
done
```