# Invalid syntax on grep command on while loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to start/stop the app server using os.system command in my python script. I have to wait until the server start/stop. I'm trying to loop through log file using grep command below. But I'm getting invalid syntax on the search string on the double quote(single quote). If i run the grep command directly it works fine. Please let me know what would be the issue or any alternative way. (I'm using Redhat enterprise linux )

```
while ! grep -m1 'Server started' < /apps/logs/messages.log; do
       sleep 1
done
```

In my python job when i tried to run the below code, I'm getting "invalid syntax" on the search string double quote (tried single quote as well). Both failing with invalid syntax error. Can you please let let me know what would be the issue. (Redhat enterprise linux).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the code. How did you run this in python? We can't help you debug if you don't show us what you did. More importantly, why in the world would you start a shell loop in python instead of having python do the looping for you?

Comment: This question is related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/323577/377345

Comment: You're also going to go wrong when the server starts and stops multiple times. Read `man pgrep`, or is there a socket the server creates, or a port it opens (read `man  lsof`).